# Print a certain number of digits after decimal point in PRINT statement in FORTRAN

Tags: fortran

I have  a double precision variable x = 10, and when I use the statement: Print(*,*) x  Fortran will print out a lengthy number as  10.0000000000000   . I only want 2 digits after the decimal point (.), that is 10.00  what should I do , instead of using Print(*,*) ? Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
   X=10
   WRITE(*,44) X
44 FORMAT(F4.2)
```

I think the FORMAT statement is what you're after. The F4.2 says to write a real in 4 columns with 2 digits after the decimal.

Comment: Hi Peter, I followed your suggestion, but it didn't work, it printed out 4 asterisk symbols instead. I am using intel fortran

Comment: ah, i've found the problem. thank you Peter, yes, all I need is to look for FORMAT statements. Thanks

Comment: However, if your real value is greater than 10 it would need at least 5 columns to be printed with 2 decimals. If you only allow 4 columns, Fortran would print asterisks, as the number does not fit in the given number of columns. (In contrast to other languages, fortran does not automatically extend the field width, if the number does not fit into.)

Comment: thank you @BálintAradi , you made it very clear and now I understand  - thanks

Comment: Just for completeness you don't need a separate statement - Write(*,'(f4.2)') X will do as well. In this case the format is simply a character string, so you can replace it with a variable which allows you to build up the format dynamically and so avoid "my god, it's full of stars!"

Comment: Thank you IanBush for your useful tip !

Comment: Alternatively you can use a single format descriptor in the print statement avoiding separeta statement: `print '(F4.2)', x`. You can read further informations about formating in https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/805-4939/z40007437a2e/index.html